# Question on permutation on combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853928/combinatorics-problem-with-repetition) post, where they ask the following question:

> Ten different people walk into a delicatessen to buy a sandwich. Four
> always order tuna fish, two always order chicken, two always order
> roast beef, and two order any of the three types of sandwich.
>
> (a) How many different sequences of sandwiches are possible?

I understand the correct answer, but I don't get why $ \frac{10!}{4!2!2!2!}3^2$ is incorrect, it is way bigger than the real answer, but it makes also sense to me, the fraction is given as the arrangement of TTTTCCRRSS (T for Tuna, C for chicken, R for RoastBeef and S for the other); and then multiply by the possibility of S to becoming T, C or R two times. Why this is not correct?

Comment: Because you are counting each configuration more than once.  Once the final list is written out, we have no idea which of the sandwiches were $S$ in your count.

Comment: TTTTCCRRSS and TTTTRRSSCC (S to becoming C, C to R, R to S) is one count.

Comment: Consider a smaller problem, two people... one orders tuna, one orders anything.  Can you list all of the possibilities here?  Can you tell the difference between TS where S becomes T and ST where S becomes T?  They both look like TT in the end, don't they?

Comment: Note, the question specified sequences *of sandwiches*.  The question did not specify that it was looking for sequences of preferences/finaldecisions.  Perhaps there is some phrasing of the question where your answer is correct where we cared which persons were the hardcore tuna lovers who only eat tuna sandwiches and nothing else versus those people who were okay with any sandwich but happened to have chosen tuna this time... but that is not the way the current question is phrased or should be interpreted.